# NSDictionary and CTypedPtrMap-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

c++ - `CTypedPtrMap<CMapWordToPtr,WORD,stTimer*> m_cAppMap;`

stTimer* is a structure containing 5 values and WORD is unsigned short which is the key.
Is it possible to store an structure object in NSDictionary.

stTimer* pEvent;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
[dictionary setObject:pEvent forKey:wTimerId];

Warnings:

> Passing argument 1 of setobject:forKey
>   from an incompatible pointer type

### EDITED

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,0,&kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,&kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    NSLog(@"Dict Size:%d\n",(int)((CFIndex)CFDictionaryGetCount(dict)));
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict,wTimerId,pEvent);
```

The key and value passed should be objects in this case. But the key(wTimerId) is an unsigned short int and not a pointer or an object.

How to pass it as a key?

### EDITED:

```
Timers.h
--------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct session {
    int a;
    char c;
    int b;
};

@interface Timers : NSObject {
    unsigned short wTimerId;
}
-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;
-(void)timer;
@end


Timers.m
--------

#import "Timers.h"


@implementation Timers

-(id)init
{
    wTimerId=91;
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)timer
{
struct session* pEvent;

    pEvent->a=10;
    pEvent->c='A';
    pEvent->b=20;


CFDictionaryValueCallBacks cbs = {0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
CFMutableDictionaryRef cfdict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,0,&kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,&cbs);
NSMutableDictionary* dict = (NSMutableDictionary*)cfdict;

    //Now both the coca approach

[dict setObject:(id)pEvent forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:wTimerId]];

//..and the CoreFoundation aproach work

    CFNumberRef timerId = CFNumberCreate(NULL,kCFNumberShortType,wTimerId);
    CFDictionarySetValue(cfdict,timerId,pEvent);
    NSLog(@"Dict size:%d\n",(int)((CFIndex)CFDictionaryGetCount(dict)));
    CFRelease(timerId);

main.m
------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Timers.h"
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Timers* time = [[Timers alloc]init];
    [time timer];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Its giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error.

### EDITED:

```
1.CFNumberRef timerId = CFNumberCreate(NULL,kCFNumberShortType,wTimerId);

2.NSLog(@"Dict size:%d\n",(int)((CFIndex)CFDictionaryGetCount(dict)));
```

warning of 1./timer/Timers.m:50:0 /timer/Timers.m:50: warning:**passing argument 3 
of 'CFNumberCreate' makes pointer from integer without a cast**

warning of 2./timer/Timers.m:52:0 /timer/Timers.m:52: warning: **passing argument 1 
of 'CFDictionaryGetCount' from incompatible pointer type**

I did as told in the warning by typecasting it into (unsigned short*) as the datatype of

wTimerId is unsigned short.It will give me another warning as **cast to pointer from integer of different size**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just pass pointers to plain structs or instances of C++ classes - `NSDictionary` expects Objective-C objects confirming to the Cocoa standards.

You could store `NSValue` instances in the dictionary using [`+valueWithPointer:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-valueWithPointer_).
Alternatively you could create a [`CFDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) directly and setup the callbacks accordingly - `CFDictionary` is toll-free bridged to `NSDictionary`, so you can use it just like before for the most part.

*Edit:*
For the key the same problem applies, you can just use `NSNumber` to wrap them. Also you can't use the default dictionary callbacks for the values, instead use something like:

```
CFDictionaryValueCallBacks cbs = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
CFMutableDictionaryRef cfdict = 
    CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &cbs);
NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)cfdict;

// now both the Cocoa approach:
[dict setObject:(id)pEvent forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:wTimerId]];
// .. and the CoreFoundation approach work:
CFNumberRef timerId = CFNumberCreate(..., &wTimerId);
CFDictionarySetValue(cfdict, timerId, pEvent);
CFRelease(timerId);
```

If you don't want to wrap the key you have to adjust the key callbacks as well.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche:Can you please explain with an example of how to search and insert elements into it.

Comment: @Beata: Are you stuck anywhere in particular? Have you started to read the documentation? No offense, but i've grown tired of people expecting complete working code instead of doing at least some research for themselves.

Comment: @Georg Fritzche:Sorry to trouble you with my little knowledge.I tried the example you explained me here and getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.I have included that code as Edit above.please see it.Thanks.

Comment: @Beata: You never initialize `pEvent` (e.g. with `pEvent = new session;`) before you start using it. Also, if you get crashes you should tell us where.

Comment: @Beata: Sorry, as you're not using Objective-C++ that should be `pEvent = malloc(sizeof(struct session));`

Comment: @Georg Fritzche:Well pointed out.That error of allocating memory to pEvent got cleared.Thanks.But i am still with the exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS and two warnings.I have edited in my post.please see it.

Comment: @Beata: You also never initialize the super-class in `-init` using [super init] - see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4) for details. Also `CFNumberCreate()` takes a *pointer* to the value, fixed that in the answer.

Comment: For the second warning you can safely cast to `CFDictionary` or just use `cfdict` instead. Note that you only need to use one of the two approaches.

Comment: @Georg Fritsche:The code works well without any errors.Fixed the errors as per you pointed out above.Thanks.